# openstack nova database show some negative value

Tags: mysql, database, openstack, openstack-nova

I have two nodes(controller, compute) and used ubuntu OS. in nova database and `compute_nodes` table, for my compute node show this:
`free_ram_mb: -4834`
how? how its negative?!

note: its worke and have not any error!

Comment: Could it be, that overcommit of ram is active on your node? (https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Documentation/HypervisorTuningGuide#Overcommitting_2) If this is configured for your machine, you can give your virtual machines more ram, than your physical node owns.

Comment: @Tobias is right, this is a clear sign of RAM being overcommitted.